# Is it feasible to crack or find a collision for a sha256 with range of 0-9

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography

If the `sha256` algorithm outputs `64`bytes hex string with in a range of [0-9], such as :-

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009
```

Is it possible to crack the given hashes?

Comment: If by 'crack' you mean determine the input that produced a given hash, cryptographers call that a first preimage attack, and no preimage attack on SHA256 is known (what the hash value is doesn't matter at all; values with many zeros are not special in any way). Bruteforcing a 256-bit space cannot be done on planet Earth, although the Bitcoin mining community can find values whose SHA256 begins with a _fairly small_ number of leading zeros (currently about 18 hex digits out of 64) at a cost in the rough vicinity of $1billion/year before the recent spike.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com ... also it is unclear since "crack" isn't a well-defined term.

Comment: [Yes, it's possible](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question). But none of the algorithms is likely to find the answer before the end of this universe.